# How to order all list elements by a vector in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a string vector:

```
 vc<-c("a", "c", "b")
```

and a list:

```
ls<-list(x<-cbind(v1=c(1, 2, 3), v2=c("a", "b","c")),
         y<-cbind(v1=c(7, 8, 0), v2=c("c", "a","b")),
         z<-cbind(v1=c(5, 6, 9), v2=c("c", "b","a")))
```

My question is how to order all elements in `ls` using column `v2` by the order of `vc`?

Comment: Fantastic! Have an answer ? +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `match` to match the values in the 2nd column with the vector.  As it is a `list`, `lapply` can be used

```
 lapply(ls, function(x) x[match(vc,x[,2]),])
```

Comment: Thanks, @akrun! one more question, what may be a better way to unlist all col `v2` into a single data frame?

Comment: @DavidZ You would get a vector with `c(sapply(ls, function(x) x[,2] ))` and then wrap it with `data.frame` to create one.

Comment: Thanks again. But this way seems not very safe. Is it right? I'm think of for-loop, but maybe there is elegant way.

Comment: @DavidZ Sorry, what is your concern? or use `unlist(lapply(...`